# Зачем в JavaScript использовать паттерн singleton?

Tags: javascript, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Разбираюсь с паттернами. Нашёл в интернете, как сделать на `JavaScript` конструктор, который бы реализовывал паттерн `singleton`. Но ведь, как я понимаю, в отличие от многих ООП языков, в `JavaScript` можно создавать объекты, не описывая классы (конструкторы), а просто создать через фигурные скобочки. Получается, можно всегда, когда в `JavaScript` нужен `singleton`, писать не конструктор его реализующий, а просто создавать глобальный объект, и пользоваться им, присваивая его другим переменным. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в этом недостатки в сравнении с созданием конструктора, реализующего `singleton`?

Comment: Думаю стоит отметить, что singleton считается _антипаттерном_. Прямого отношения к вопросу это не имеет, но может быть полезно для вашего дальнейшего роста =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формально, эти самые 'фигурные скобочки' тоже создаются через конструктор `new Object`, как и примитивы через обёртки.

В пространстве JS, где всё непостоянно и специфично (во всяком случае было когда-то), этот паттерн не очень-то нужен.

Сейчас, когда JS вырос из песочницы браузеров и занимает внушительную нишу, он может использовать Singleton для взрослых целей, где после инициализации менять ничего не нужно: одно подключение к БД, один объект пользователя/сессии и пр.

Впрочем, с новыми возможностями ([`Object.seal`](http://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal), [`Object.preventExtensions`](http://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions), [`Object.freeze`](http://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)), этот паттерн опять же не нужен - всё решено изящнее и в духе языка (ИМХО).

Comment: [_These are fixed values, not variables, that you literally provide in your script._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Literals), То есть это не совсем _тоже создаются через конструктор new Object,_

Comment: @Grundy Я и не сказал что это точно так. Это обёртки, которые живут ровно столько, сколько интерпретируется текущая команда. Хотя может и ошибаюсь.